# Change template after login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

I'm trying to change the page after authentication but nothing happens unless I click again at the login button.

Here is the code :

```
myApp.controller('AuthController', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location) {
    // (1)    $location.path('/produtos');
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.pass = '';

    $scope.submit = function() {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebasedb.firebaseio.com/");

        ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : $scope.email,
            password : $scope.pass
        }, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login failed !", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Login ok ! "); // (2)
                $location.path('/produtos');
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Below are the observations -

1. The commented instruction at (1) works ok
2. The message at (2) is correctly printed at the console

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$location.path` will work only if you run digest cycle..wrap that in `$timeout`

Comment: Hi Pankaj, it worked with : 

                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path("/produtos");
                });

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something interrupts location change. Try `setTimeout(function(){$location.path('/produtos');}, 0);` - that helps in such situations.

Comment: Hi, and what about $timeout as Pankaj said?

Comment: I'm looking on how do that ( run digest cycle..wrap that in $timeout ) ( newbie on Angular.. )

Comment: Worked with                 
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
                   $location.path("/produtos");
 });